# Accessing overridden method of a private inner class with private constructor

Tags: java, inner-classes, access-modifiers

Please find the below snippet :
**class Rule**

```
public class Rules {

    public static final JarvisFilterRule FILTER = new JarvisFilterRule();

    private static class JarvisFilterRule extends RelOptRule {
        private JarvisFilterRule() {
            super(operand(Filter.class, operand(Query.class, none())));
        }

        public void onMatch(RelOptRuleCall call) {
        // do something
        }
    }
}
```

**class RelOptRule**

```
public abstract class RelOptRule {

  /**
   * Description of rule, must be unique within planner. Default is the name
   * of the class sans package name, but derived classes are encouraged to
   * override.
   */
    protected final String description;
    public abstract void onMatch(RelOptRuleCall call);
}
```

My question is : **How can I access the onMatch() method of nested class Rules.JarvisFilterRule?**

Comment: The `onMatch` method is an _instance_ method, so you do not "access the onMatch() method of inner _class_". You could call the method on the new `JarvisFilterRule` instance that is referenced by the constant `FILTER`. Simply call `Rules.FILTER.onMatch(...)`. Besides that, your code doesn't compile, and your question is very unclear.

Comment: till Rules.FILTER, I do not get any error. But when I call the Rules.FILTER.onMatch(..) , I get a compilation error "The type Rules.JarvisFilterRule is not visible".

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `private` key word is to prevent access to class members that need to be used exclusively by the class declaring it.

In your case, the `Rules` class defines `JarvisFilterRule` to be a `private` inner class with the intention that its implementation should be known only to the `Rules` class.

If you wish to access the `JarvisFilterRule::onMatch()` method inside another class, you will need to replace the `private` modifier of `JarvisFilterRule` with `public` or move the inner class `JarvisFilterRule` to its own separate file and make it a `public` class. Like this:

> **JarvisFilterRule .java**

```
public class JarvisFilterRule extends RelOptRule {
        public JarvisFilterRule() {
            super(operand(Filter.class, operand(Query.class, none())));
        }

        public void onMatch(RelOptRuleCall call) {
        // do something
        }
    }
```

**-- OR --**

```
public class Rules {

    public static final JarvisFilterRule FILTER = new JarvisFilterRule();

    public static class JarvisFilterRule extends RelOptRule {
        private JarvisFilterRule() {
            super(operand(Filter.class, operand(Query.class, none())));
        }

        public void onMatch(RelOptRuleCall call) {
        // do something
        }
    }
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`Rules.FILTER.onMatch(...)`

`JarvisFilterRule` is not an inner class. An inner class in Java is a nested class that is not static.